# How was I able to change imported value in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

```
//lib-es6.js

export let counter = 3;
export function incCounter() {
  counter++;
}
```

From [16.7.2 section](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_imports-as-views-on-exports), its given that, even if we import a module via asterisk (*) the imported value cant be changed.

```
//main-es6.js

import * as lib from './lib-es6'; // imported via asterisk(*)

// The imported value `counter` is live
console.log(lib.counter); // 3 . => I expected this
lib.incCounter();
console.log(lib.counter); // 4 . => I expected this

/****************************************/ 
// But I was able to change lib.counter.
// Question: Can we change imported value in ES6 if we import it via asterisk (*)?
lib.counter++; // Not an error. ==> I DID NOT expected this.
console.log(lib.counter); // 5
/****************************************/
```

Comment: My guess: `lib` refers to an object with a `counter` property, and said property is not immutable.

Comment: Are you running the code directly in node (in that case which version) or are you compiling it via something like babel first?

Comment: @Markus-ipse Yes, I am using babel7,  node10. I am running using     "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
"@babel/node": "^7.4.5"

Comment: Looks like your transpiler doesn't pick up this mistake. It might depend on the babel options, but `.counter` should be a getter without a setter.

Answer (score 3):

You are not really executing an ES module, you are executing a CommonJS module (that was transpiled from an ES module). You should get the expected result if you run this code natively:

- On Node.js 12 with `--experimental-modules`: [The new ECMAScript module support in Node.js 12](http://2ality.com/2019/04/nodejs-esm-impl.html)
- In a modern browser.

Comment: Hi @Axel 
1. I tried node.js 12 with --experimental-modules. Its still unable to resolve lib-es6.

2. How to run it in a browser without bundling it using babel ? Any jsfiddle link is helpful for reference.
3. I tried running using [yarn add esm], [node -r esm main-es6.js]

Still same output. No error.

Comment: Hi @Axel, if I am executing CommonJS modules, how come unqualified imports are working fine and throwing an error as expected when i did counter++. It should not throw an error if it is commonJS right when i increment a local copy ?

Comment: The best way to explore ES modules is by using them in their pure form, without any transpilation. If you transpile, your only choice is to look at the transpiled code.